# Propositional logic symbolization

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having issues to symbolize the following statement:

"Yes, I rather have peace, forgiveness is needed. Being pro-war also means to accept the consequences and cost of war. If forgiveness is necessary; as consequence I understand the price. At the end I prefer peace or I prefer war , therefore I conclude: No accepting the social cost that war brings implies a grade of impunity"

I tried this (with propositional logic):

$$p→q$$
$$s→r$$
$$q→t$$
$$∴(¬p∨p)→(¬r∨t)$$

How do I succeed?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: $(→r∨t)$ is not well-formed; you cannot start a formula with a *connective* different from $\lnot$.

Comment: Why you have used $t$ both for "To understand the price of war" and for "a grade of impunity" ?

Comment: Back up and re-symbolize the argument.  Maybe make some sort of definition guide also to keep track of each letter that stands for a proposition.